# Team sports in olympics

Tags: olympics, international-sports

- What are the team sports that have been added in the Olympics?
- When was football added to the Olympics?
- What team sport will be added in Olympics 2016?

---

- Who will decide [when Cricket will be added to the Olympics](ICC or Olympics committee)?

  - See: [How does a sport become an Olympic Sport?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/255/how-does-a-sport-become-an-olympic-sport?rq=1)

Comment: I would ask Q4 separately as it plays "one unlike the others" in this case. However, Q4 seems speculatory in regards to Cricket but I am open to any **factual** progress in terms of its (re)introduction to the Olympics. However, your follow up (similar) [question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/255/how-does-a-sport-become-an-olympic-sport?rq=1) has been asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia offers a pretty good list for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_Sports#Summer_Olympics

Football was added 1900.
Rugby sevens will be added 2016.

A list of team sports can be found in the list on wikipedia. **Team sports in 2012 olympics were volleyball, football, badminton, basketball and handball**.

Cricket was in the olympics in 1900 only and there is no info when it will be added again.

IOC decides.