# What are the reasons that cricket is not included in the Olympics?

Tags: cricket, history, olympics

I found online that it was last played in the 1900 Olympics. It hasn't been played since. What are the reasons that cricket is no longer included as an Olympic sport?

Comment: Not quite an exact duplicate but to supplement your question: http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1813/team-sports-in-olympics

Comment: @kartshan "Not quite an exact duplicate but to supplement your question" shows that I am aware the questions are different.

Comment: As "not constructive," not "exact duplicate." Two different reasons.