# Has rugby been an Olympic sport prior to the 2016 Olympics?

Tags: history, olympics, rugby

Rugby Sevens will be played as part of the 2016 Olympics, but has any form of rugby been played in any previous Olympic Games?

Comment: Not sure *why* is answerable (I think we've had the same question on cricket, for example). The second part is.

Comment: @Joe https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/what-are-the-reasons-that-cricket-is-not-included-in-the-olympics

Comment: @Joe: I think it is answerable - traditional 15-a-side rugby requires a lot of recovery time and games are played 6/7 days apart. This means a tournament takes at least 6-7 weeks to run and couldn't fit into the modern (3-4 week) Olympic schedule (the 1924 Olympics ran for 12+ weeks). Sevens is suitable because it has short, less contact-orientated games which allow a tournament to be completed over several days. Sevens has only recently been taken seriously enough on its own to be a sport that's up to Olympic standards, which is why it's now included.

Comment: @Niall That would probably be a good answer to the closely related *What reasons might Rugby not have been an olympic sport* or similar, but *Why* means we need to know the actual reasons the Olympic committee did not include it - short of them publishing something indicating that, we can't know for sure (for example, that it wasn't more a political decision).  You're probably right - but 'probably' isn't the aim of this site...

Comment: @Joe: Fair point, and certainly that middle part would be required for an answer. It likely exists though. Subsequent olympics were 2 weeks long. Such a drastic change (a 12week to 2 week schedule) would have involved a lot of discussion and it's likely that records survive along with something to the effect of "sports that take too long will be excluded".

Answer (score 3):

It was stopped back in 1924, but it appears to be back:  http://usarugby.org/2016-rio-olympics

Answer (score 3):

15-a-side Rugby Union was included in the 1900 (Paris), 1904 (London), 1920 (Antwerp) and 1924 (Paris) Olympic Games, but as would be expected for that age there was only a men's competition.

The gold medals in 1920 and 1924 went to the United States team.

http://www.rugbyfootballhistory.com/olympics.htm#usa1924