# Why isn't Cricket an Olympics sport event?

Tags: rules, cricket, olympics

Olympics is the biggest sporting event on earth, but there are still some spots that are not included in the Olympics like **Cricket**. It is now a much more popular sport over the world but there are still no sign of it becoming an Olympics sport.

Comment: new edit also resembles this closed question [What are the reasons that cricket is not included in the Olympics?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2147/what-are-the-reasons-that-cricket-is-not-included-in-the-olympics)

Comment: PSA: this question is being discussed on [meta](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/813/what-should-we-do-to-this-question).

Answer (score 0):

For Tokyo 2020, the relevant criteria as expressed by the organizing committee was: added value; youth appeal; attractiveness for TV, media and the general public; gender equality; minimum impact on the number of events and/or quotas, infrastructure and operational costs and complexity [(1)](http://www.topendsports.com/events/summer/sport-selection.htm).

Following these criteria, five sports were added: baseball/softball, karate, skateboarding, sport climbing and surf. Basically, two very popular sports in Japan and three radical sports very popular amongst the youth; all of them played in multiple countries and by both genres. Also, basketball 3x3 was added but not considered as a new sport, just a variation of the basketball 5x5.

Comment: Can you provide specific reasons why Kabbadi is not included in Olympic although it is having short time period.

Comment: Kabbadi is virtually unknown outside of southern Asia. Only 31 countries are in its international federation. It is nowhere near being an Olympic sport.

Comment: Just to confirm Nij comment, I'm Brazilian, lived in Italy and now I'm in USA. I never heard of Kabbadi.

Comment: @MFornari [Kabbadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabaddi) is an ancient Indian sport very much popular in India and Indian sub continent.
India is top nation in Kabbadi won all the three [World Cup(Standard Style)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabaddi_World_Cup_(Standard_style))